# Can't access or instantiate newly created classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a problem in regards to my project, as the title said: I can't access or instantiate newly created classes. I am using Visual Studio Community 2019, and this is the first time I encountered this problem.

[image: Here is the structure of my main project]

Now, whenever I create a new class, let's say **MyClass.cs**, I usually declare it as public, and within the namespace of the project. I added a simple function that returns a string. So, the code would be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CASAPI
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Weee()
        {
            return "weee";
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I call this class on my Controllers, I can't call the class.

```
using CASAPI;


namespace CASAPI.Controllers.API
{
    public class FingerprintController : ApiController
    {

        private readonly SerialPort _port;

        public FingerprintController()
        {
            _port = new SerialPort();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/sms/sendmessage")]
        public IHttpActionResult SMSSendMessage(SMSVM smsData)
        {
            try
            {

                MyClass whut = new MyClass(); //errors here

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to rack my brains out as to what the problem is but I can't seem to find what is wrong, even though it looks so simple. Has anyone ever experienced this? And if so, how did you fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post then. :)

Comment: Hover to red line error, what message it shown?

Comment: Is the class in the same project as the controller? Have you got a reference to the project that it is in?

Comment: The namespace CASAPI is the same as the project name, could this be causing a problem?

Comment: @HienNguyen here's what it shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwjiJ.png

Comment: Namespaces are irrelevant if the project which contains the class isn't referenced. No reference, no see.

Comment: You can click to the yellow light to add class reference

Comment: @upsidedowncreature I doubt it, I have another class built earlier within the same namespace and it works fine. But the new classes I create under the namespace suddenly is not seen..

Comment: @SteveTodd what do you mean sir? I don't get what you meant by "if the project which contains the class isn't referenced."

Comment: @Steve Todd agreed, but from the screenshot it looks like MyClass and the controller are in the same project so I'm grasping at straws a bit.

Comment: A Visual Studio solution can be built from multiple projects. Library code is often in a separate project for example. You need a reference in the project  which is going to use the code before it can be seen.

Comment: @HienNguyen even when the classes are created via the intellisense, I still can't create an instance of the object.. I've been on this for hours and I can't seem to solve it or find a solution..

Comment: Where about is this object in the folder structure? ASP.NET can get stroppy if you have objects in the wrong folder.

Comment: @SteveTodd the object that works you mean? On my screenshot I sent to HienNguyen, it's the GeneralComponents.cs. The namespace is just the same as the MyClass.cs sample sir.

Comment: @SteveTodd I did find a small difference between them tho sir. Look at this screenshot.. GlobalComponents.cs has a dropdown wherein all the functions created are listed, while the MyClass.cs, the functions are not listed. I wonder what does this impy.. https://imgur.com/qO2BRuG

Comment: That would imply that there's something about the class that the compiler does not like. What namespace is GlobalComponents.cs in?

Comment: @SteveTodd same as what I used in MyClass.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to solve this by adding the new classes on my project, and restarting my Visual Studio.. It's a bit weird tho, but that's how I solved it.

Comment: For me cleaning and rebuilding the solution before closing everything worked.